# Expectation of a constant diagonal matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, probability

**Is the expected value of a diagonal matrix with constant entries equal to the mean value of the entries?**

My question stems from the following observation in a paper.

Given a real diagonal matrix 
$\Lambda_{i}[n] = \mathrm{diag}\{\rho_{i,1}[n], \rho_{i,2}[n], \dots, \rho_{i,N}[n]\}$, where $\rho_{i,q}[n] = J_{0} \left(\frac{2 \pi v^{(i,q)} f_{c} n T_{s}}{c}\right)$ and $v^{(i,q)}$ is a random variable uniformly distributed in $(0, V_{\mathrm{max}})$, it is shown that

$$ \mathbb E[\Lambda_{i}[n] (\Lambda_{i}([n])^{H} ] = \mathbb E[(\Lambda_{i}[n])^{2}] = \bar{\lambda}[n] \textbf{I}_{N}$$

where $\bar{\lambda}[n] = \frac{1}{V_{\mathrm{max}}} \int_{0}^{V_{max}} J_{0}^{2}(\frac{2\pi v f_{c} n T_{s}}{c}) dv$ is the mean value of the diagonal entries in $(\Lambda_{i}[n])^{2}$.

Using the above observation I wish to evaluate the following expression:

$$\mathbb E[\Lambda_{i}[n] \mathrm{D_{\eta_{i}}}[n] (\Lambda_{i}([n])^{H} ]$$

where, $\mathrm{D_{\eta_{i}}}[n] = \mathrm{diag}\{\eta_{i,1}, \eta_{i,2}, \dots, \eta_{i, N}\}$  is a diagonal matrix with constant entries. Is it correct to evaluate the expression as follows?

$$\mathbb E[\Lambda_{i}[n] \mathrm{D_{\eta_{i}}}[n] (\Lambda_{i}([n])^{H} ] = \bar{\eta_{i}}[n] \bar{\lambda}[n]$$

where, $\bar{\eta_{i}}[n] = \frac{\eta_{i,1} + \eta_{i,2} + \dots + \eta_{i,N}}{N}$ and $\bar{\lambda}[n] = \frac{1}{V_{max}} \int_{0}^{V_{max}} J_{0}^{2}(\frac{2\pi v f_{c} n T_{s}}{c}) dv$

If yes, is there a proof for it?

Comment: I think this would be better of on math.SE than here, no?

Comment: Hi: Assuming that I understand the notation , you have an  $n \times n$ matrix of random variables  multiplied by a constant $n \times n$ matrix which is then multiplied by the transpose of the $n \times n$ matrix of random variables. So, if the middle matrix really is a constant, then you can pull it outside of the multiplication and multiply by it later so your answer will just be  $D_{\eta_{i}}[n] \times \bar \lambda(n) \times {I}_{n}$. Note that this depends crucially on the middle matrix being constants.

Comment: Note that you end up with a scalar and I end up with a $n \times n$ matrix so I have a feeling that I'm mis-understanding something.

Comment: Apologies, I just confused myself. You're right, the $\mathrm{D_{\eta_{i}}}[n]$ simply comes out and the result is an $n \times n $ matrix. Thanks!

Comment: Hi: I'm glad it helped. And it helped me because I don't deal with matrices much these days so it was nice to say hello to them :).